# python expand a list to print

Tags: python, list, printing, format

If I have a list

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

How do I expand it so that I can print something like

```
print '%s %s %s' % (*lst) ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortened form of mgilson's answer, for code golf purposes

```
>>> l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> print(*l)
A B C
```

Answer (score 8):

These days, you'd use `format` instead:

```
"{} {} {}".format(*lst)  #python 2.7 and newer
"{0} {1} {2}".format(*lst) #python 2.6 and newer
```

Comment: What if we have 1000000000000 items?

Comment: Then you don't do it this way :).  Based on how the question was phrased, OP makes it sound like the number of elements is small and known -- but (clearly), I'm making a guess at this.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use string formatting the way you outlined, you have to convert the list to a tuple beforehand.

```
>>> l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> print '%s %s %s' % tuple(l)
A B C
```

However, in this case I'd recommend something like

```
>>> print " ".join(l)
A B C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print '%s %s %s' % tuple(lst)
A B C
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, your best bet is to use `str.join`:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print ' '.join(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.join(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method:

```
print " ".join(lst)
```

This way the code won't break if list will have different number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is abit unclear.. But if I understand correctly; you can add things to a list using append, and you can print your list using a simple print function. Example

```
list = ["A", "B", "C"]
list.append("D") #ADDS "D" TO THE LIST
print list #Will print all strings in list
```

Sorry if this doesn't help. I do what I can. (: